# Why are human faces not drawn in old cartoons?

Tags: animation

This question torments me from childhood. In old cartoons like Tom and Jerry human faces are not drawn. But since 5th volume (not precisely) human faces were introduced.

Why? Was it difficult for animators to draw them? Was it a time-saving measure or something else?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To represent Animal perspective.

The Tom and Jerry cartoon is about animals, they have to show their perspective. Humans are larger to them, they can't even see their full body together. So it's kept that way. Humans are not even a regular cast, so why to bother to make their faces when it isn't needed. It also helps to make the audience focus on Tom and Jerry only.

But later they included human faces maybe for fan requests or for unknown reasons. If I am not wrong then in the earlier episodes human roles are very few to negligible but later some humans become partially regular.

Comment: "Ant can walk around human hand, but unable to tell others about what happened to him". Seems you are totally right.

Comment: The Peanuts comic strips and animated cartoons likewise omit adults, opposing baseball players, etc.  I'm not sure of the chronology of the technique; I'm pretty certain that Tom and Jerry animated cartoons predate the Peanuts ones, but the Peanuts comic strips go back well before that.

Answer (score 4):

Animal perspective has nothing to do with it, it's so they don't have to animate the face for the speaking - they can change the script without having to re-animate

Comment: Thank you for assisting the community. Ideas for framing an answer may include describing your sources along with a synopsis of what they said, and/or adding links to the resources and visuals you’ve found. I hope you enjoy participating.

Comment: And in the case of *Peanuts*, you don't even have to overdub.